# How to find visible element and perform click action in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I have one window on which i have four links

1. Exit Button Link - `<a id="exitBtn" class="x-btn questionpreview_exitbtn_sb x-unselectable x-btn-toolbar x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-toolbar-small-noicon" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" hidefocus="on" style="right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 0px;">`
2. Submit button Link - `<a id="submitBtn" class="x-btn questionpreview_submitbtn_sb x-unselectable x-btn-toolbar x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-toolbar-small-noicon" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" hidefocus="on" style="right: auto; left: 864px; top: 0px; margin: 0px;">`
3. Back Button Link - `<a id="prevBtn" class="x-btn questionpreview_backbtn_sb x-unselectable x-btn-toolbar x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-toolbar-small-noicon" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" hidefocus="on" style="right: auto; left: 733px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; display: none;">`
4. Review Button Link - `<a id="reviewBtn" class="x-btn questionpreview_reviewbtn_sb x-unselectable x-btn-toolbar x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-toolbar-small-noicon" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" hidefocus="on" style="right: auto; left: 798px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; display: none;">`

Out of these five button only two button (Exit and Submit) are visible on first window. When I click on submit button having using this locator:

```
xpath=//*[contains(text(),'Question Preview')]/ancestor::div[6]//div[@id="previewWindow-body"]//div[@id="preview-top-container"]//*[contains(text(),'Submit')]/ancestor::a`
```

it works and the next window opens. On next window submit button gets hidden and it shows exit, back and Review button

They look like this

1. Exit button - `<a id="exitBtn" class="x-btn questionpreview_exitbtn_sb x-unselectable x-btn-toolbar x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-toolbar-small-noicon" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" hidefocus="on" style="right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 0px;">`
2. Back Button - `<a id="prevBtn" class="x-btn questionpreview_backbtn_sb x-unselectable x-btn-toolbar x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-toolbar-small-noicon" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" hidefocus="on" style="right: auto; left: 798px; top: 0px; margin: 0px;">`
3. Review Button - `<a id="reviewBtn" class="x-btn questionpreview_reviewbtn_sb x-unselectable x-btn-toolbar x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-toolbar-small-noicon" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" hidefocus="on" style="right: auto; left: 863px; top: 0px; margin: 0px;">`

My question is when next window opens I could not click any or find any of these three buttons. I am using xpath for back button as
`//*[contains(text(),'Back')]/ancestor::a[@id="prevBtn" and not(contains(@style,'display: none'))]` but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If your code opens a new window, and you want to interact with that window, you need to call the [Select Window](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Select%20Window) keyword to let selenium know which window to look for the given elements.